# Conversão de imagens com PHP

Tags: php, firebird

É meu primeiro dia com php e estou fazendo um select que me retorna uma imagen, como faço para renderizar esta imagem. Segue meu select e o retorno da imagem:

```
class CooperMaisController {

public function getItens(){
    $connect = OpenConnection();
    $query = ibase_query($connect, " select * from CAD_PROD_PONTUACAO_RESGATE PP left join CAD_PRODUTOS CP on CP.EMPRESA = PP.EMPRESA and  CP.CODIGO = PP.PRODUTO ");

    if ($query){                
        $pagamentos = array();          
        while ($row = ibase_fetch_object($query)){              
            $pagamento = new coopermais();
            $pagamento->setCodigo($row->CODIGO);
            $pagamento->setPontuacao($row->PONTUACAO);
            $pagamento->setNome($row->NOME);
            $pagamento->setFoto($row->FOTO);                
            $pagamentos[] = $pagamento;         
        }           
        return $pagamentos;
    } else {
        return "Erro: ".ibase_errmsg();
    }

    unset($row);
    unset($query);
    ibase_close($connect);
   }    
}
```

Quando dou um `var_dump` na imagem visualizo isso:
[image: inserir a descrição da imagem aqui]

Estou acostumando com JavaScript e node onde salvava a imagem convertida no banco como base 64 (ficava uma string enorme), agora com php ao salvar a imagem aparece isto:

[image: inserir a descrição da imagem aqui]

Quando olho no as XML a imagem é renderizada.

Comment: O campo é `BLOB` com o `sub_type` como `binary`?

Comment: Sim um campo blob binary com size 80, consigo visualizar a imagem perfeitamente no banco.

Comment: 80 é muito pouco, será que a imagem não truncou?

Answer (score 0):

Não estou bem certo, mas acho que tenha que converter para `VARCHAR`

```
SELECT *, CAST(SUBSTRING(blob1 FROM 1 FOR 80) AS VARCHAR(80)) AS IMAGECHAR
```

E passaria assim:

```
$pagamento->setFoto($row->IMAGECHAR);
```

No entanto se for exibir em um HTML talvez tenha que usar *data URI scheme*, ou seja a imagem terá que ser convertida em base64, pra usar o data URI é necessário saber o mimetype da imagem será necessário ativar no PHP do seu servidor a extensão `file_info`, o código deve ficar assim:

um exemplo genérico só para entender:

```
function mimeType($data)
{
    $mimetype = false;

    if (class_exists('finfo')) {
        $finfo = finfo_open(FILEINFO_MIME_TYPE);
        $mimetype = finfo_buffer($finfo, $data);
        finfo_close($finfo);
    }

    return $mimetype ? $mimetype : 'imagem/jpeg'; //jpeg será um fallback pra facilitar
}

...

while ($row = ibase_fetch_object($query)){              
    $imagem = base64_encode($row->IMAGECHAR);

    echo '<img src="data:image/jpeg;base64,', base64_encode($imagem),'">';
}

...
```